# AdminLTE Roles dude

Tags: laravel, roles, user-roles, adminlte

I'm working on a Laravel project with AdminLTE 3. I'm trying to configure the left dashboard menu items to display different options based on the user's role. I believe this involves modifying the 'adminlte.php' file, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone help me with this?

```
'menu' => [
        // Navbar items:
        [
            'type'         => 'navbar-search',
            'text'         => 'search',
            'topnav_right' => true,
        ],
        [
            'type'         => 'fullscreen-widget',
            'topnav_right' => true,
        ],

        // Sidebar items:
        [
            'type' => 'sidebar-menu-search',
            'text' => 'search',
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'blog',
            'url'  => 'admin/blog',
            'can'  => 'manage-blog',
        ],
        ['header' => 'Opciones de Perfil'],
        [
            'text' => ' Perfil',
            'url'  => 'profile',
            'icon' => 'fas fa-fw fa-user',
        ],
```

I have tried with @role('admin1') @endrole, but it's not correct.